# Why does Android app not play videos but only the audio of a video?

Tags: android, html, cordova, html5-video, cordova-plugins

I made an Android app that runs smoothly on Android device but somehow it won't work on some devices.

Then I read about Cordova crosswalk webview (https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview) as this plugin is the best choice when your HTML5 app uses any of the advanced HTML5 features that are not supported in the default Android WebViews (https://software.intel.com/en-us/xdk/docs/why-use-crosswalk-for-android-builds).

By using this plugin, Cordova build two apks i.e android-armv7-debug.apk and android-x86-debug.apk. Then I install the arm apk as x86 is not supported for that android device architecture, but still it not  play videos?

And the most surprising thing is that, it not  play videos in other devices too that was run smoothly before this plugin.

Comment: Please don't deface your post by rolling back our improvements!

Answer (score 0):

For this ! go with exoplayer , integrate it within your app ,Best player for videos in an app